# iOS PencilKit Draw shapes programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, apple-pencil, pencilkit

I'm trying to figure out how to modify the `PKDrawing` property from `PKCanvasView` to add some shapes like circles or at least add a line however `PKDrawing` is an opaque type so there is not too much to do.

Is there any workaround to create shapes or lines on a `PKCanvasView` ?

Comment: I have been searching high and low for an answer to this.  From what I can tell you cannot programmatically modify the data in a PKDrawing object

Answer (score 2):

You can now

```
yourPKCanvasView.drawing = PKDrawing(strokes: yourPKStrokes)
```

Full example:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/inspecting_modifying_and_constructing_pencilkit_drawings

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to create the drawing 100% programmatically, from raw CGPoints, instead of from a predefined asset like in Apple's examples, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70274331/4075379